# Calculate average for multiple subsets simultaneously

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I have a MySQL database (for testing: through WAMP) with among other things a collection of temperatures for a bunch of likewise devices.
Now I want to calculate the average temperature for each device individually. I can do so for one device at a time, but it would greatly reduce the number of queries if more can be done simultaneously.

Small DB example:

| ID | RecdAtUnix | dev_eui* | temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1683528566 | A | 19.8 |
| 1 | 1683528567 | A | 20.5 |
| 2 | 1683528568 | B | 22.3 |
| 3 | 1683528569 | C | 21.0 |
| 4 | 1683528570 | B | 24.9 |
| 5 | 1683528571 | C | 23.6 |
| 6 | 1683528572 | A | 18.4 |

* dev_eui is a string that uniquely identifies a device

An example query:

```
SELECT theInterval,

round(avg(temperature), 4) AS temperature

FROM (

    SELECT (RecdAtUnix - (RecdAtUnix % (:interval))) as theInterval,

    temperature

    FROM Uplinks
    WHERE RecdAtUnix >= :start AND RecdAtUnix < :end AND dev_eui = :dev_eui
    ORDER BY RecdAtUnix

) AS someData

GROUP BY theInterval ORDER BY theInterval;
```

This query returns (among others) the average temperature over a specified interval for a specific `dev_eui`. For `dev_eui = A` this would return average temperature 19.5667 for the whole interval.
(How) can I calculate the average for all / a number of `dev_eui`s at once?
All possible values of `dev_eui`s are known through another table.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: this should help a bit - please let me know if I missed some crucial information / example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by two fields. So in this case you can start with:

```
SELECT
 theInterval,
 dev_eui,
 round(avg(temperature), 4) AS temperature

FROM (
    SELECT
      (RecdAtUnix - (RecdAtUnix % (:interval))) as theInterval,
      dev_eui,
      temperature

    FROM Uplinks
    WHERE RecdAtUnix >= :start AND RecdAtUnix < :end
) AS someData

GROUP BY theInterval, dev_eui
ORDER BY theInterval, dev_eui;
```

And do not include `order by` in a subquery - waste of performance.

EDIT:
The MySQL can do a group by over calculated value, so this can be reduced to:

```
    SELECT
      (RecdAtUnix - (RecdAtUnix % (:interval))) as theInterval,
      dev_eui,
      temperature

    FROM Uplinks
    WHERE RecdAtUnix >= :start AND RecdAtUnix < :end

    GROUP BY theInterval, dev_eui
    ORDER BY theInterval, dev_eui;
```

Comment: good point regarding the ordering - remnants of some older query but irrelevant here. Is there a more elegant way to expand this to ~50 `dev_eui`s?

Comment: If you do not need to split data by "theInterval", then simple `select dev_eui, avg(temperature) from uplinks group by dev_eui` will be enough.

Comment: thanks for the addition! it is somewhat okay, but in the ideal world I would like to plot a figure where the data is averaged per "theInterval" for each device. do you have any decent suggestion or is that not really achievable?

Comment: @StevenCellist it is possible in MySQL. I edited the answer.